# mysql result from table1 where table2 doesn't match AND between start_datetime and start_datetime + 8 hours

Tags: mysql, datetime, join, date-arithmetic

I want to query a list of employee ids from table `employees`, but exclude the employee ids that are already in a separate table called `employee_schedule` if it falls between a specific `datetime` and that same `datetime + 8 hours`.  I'm not using datetime for end of shift for other reasons.

```
SELECT user_id
FROM employees AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN employee_schedule AS t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.assigned_guard_id
WHERE t2.assigned_guard_id IS NULL
AND ('2017-10-23 18:00:00' BETWEEN t2.shift_start 
AND ADDTIME(t2.shift_start, '12:00:00'))
```

Result:

```
`employees` |  `employee_schedule`
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id          |  guard_assigned_id, shift_start(datetime), shift_duration(INT, minutes)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
17          |  17, '2017-10-23 18:00:00', '480'
19          |  
22          |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Result should only show `19` and `22`, since 17 shows up in the schedule between `shift_start` and `shift_start + shift_duration`.

My query is returning 0 results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your range condition is converting the LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN. The two conditions can never be true for the same row. You need to move the second condition to the ON clause of the LEFT JOIN. So it should be:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM employees AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN employee_schedule AS t2
    ON  t1.user_id = t2.assigned_guard_id
    AND '2017-10-23 18:00:00' BETWEEN t2.shift_start
        AND ADDTIME(t2.shift_start, '12:00:00')
WHERE t2.assigned_guard_id IS NULL
```

Note that the engine might not be able to optimize the range condition to use an index. It could be better to write it as

```
AND t2.shift_start <= '2017-10-23 18:00:00'
AND t2.shift_start >= SUBTIME('2017-10-23 18:00:00', '12:00:00')
```

or

```
AND t2.shift_start BETWEEN SUBTIME('2017-10-23 18:00:00', '12:00:00')
    AND '2017-10-23 18:00:00'
```

If you want to use `shift_duration` instead of a constant time, you can use

```
AND t2.shift_start <= '2017-10-23 18:00:00'
AND t2.shift_start >= '2017-10-23 18:00:00' - INTERVAL shift_duration MINUTE
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have been banging my head over for several days!  Thank for a very concise answer with alternative options included.